# How to load partial with using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Indeed, in spite of setting ajax loading as 'remote=>true', it loads the url

> '/noajax_en/v/yt/' + @movie.uid + '/refresh_part_after_comment'

Why it won't load ajax? it should load the url this below

> '/en/v/yt/' + @movie.uid + '/refresh_part_after_comment'

Here's my code

**view**

```
<%= form_for(@comment, :url => {:controller => "comments", :action => "create" }, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, id:"body_input" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :elapsed_time, id: "elapsed_time" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :video_id, value: params[:uid] %>
    <%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-primary") do %>
        Post
    <% end %>                   
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
def create
    .
    .
    .
    flash[:notice] = "posted"       

    if request.xhr?  # ajax request
        respond_to do |format|
            render '/en/v/yt/' + @movie.uid + '/refresh_part_after_comment'
        end
    else
            redirect_to '/noajax_en/v/yt/' + @movie.uid + '/refresh_part_after_comment'
    end
end
```

Comment: Try taking the `respond_to do |format|` block out, ie just doing the `render` line inside the `request.xhr?` case.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Thanks for a comment. It's still the same even if I take it out.

Comment: @MKK where you want to render the partial? should it load some content and replace something in the view?

Comment: @rob yes that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

couple things wrong..

form_for  needs: remote: true in options

in your controller.. no need to check the request object.. respond_to already does that:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {# redirect here}
  format.js do
    render 'view name.js.erb'  # or leave out to render default view.js.erb for action
  end
end
```